# Folding via foldexpr

Tags: folding

I have the following file

```
#
#
NODE  / 11000001       1009.6809       -878.9679        316.3049
NODE  / 11000001       1009.6809       -878.9679        316.3049
NODE  / 11000001       1009.6809       -878.9679        316.3049
NODE  / 11000001       1009.6809       -878.9679        316.3049
```

I'd like to fold it using the foldexpr method (I tried syntax, but I have other requirements that for now keep me from pursuing that further). There should be 2 folds, one containing the first 2 lines, a second containing the other. If need be, I'd be ok with a third fold containing the other two, but I'd like it better if this could be avoided.

`:h fold-expr` refers to `:h fold-indent` for using foldlevels:

> A sequence of lines with the same or higher fold level form a fold,
>   with the lines with a higher level forming a nested fold.

So, as far as I can see, I need to have the first 2 lines the same foldlevel, as well as lines 3-6. But lines 1-2 need a higher foldlevel, so the fold for lines 1-2 fold does not include lines 3-6. I can achieve that in the following way

```
set foldexpr=GetPamFold(v:lnum)

function! GetPamFold(lnum)
  let linestr = getline(a:lnum)

  if linestr =~ '^NODE'
    return '2'
  elseif linestr =~ '^#'
    return '3'
  endif

  return '0'
```

I can check the foldlevels via `echom foldlevel(1)` and such, and it works as expected.

What does not work is the folding itself. I get 2 folds: 1 containing the first 2 lines (good), and a second containing the first fold and lines 3-6. That's bad. Also, both those folds are each contained in another fold that ONLY contains the other fold, i.e. trivially folds the 1 line (e.g. the folded lines 1-2) into one line. Really bad.

To clarify:

- Fold1 contains lines 1-2
- Fold2 contains Fold1
- Fold3 contains Fold2 and lines 3-6
- Fold4 contains Fold3

As far as I can see, it's not what the docs say what would happen. What am I missing? What can I do to achieve my folds?

I'm using vim 7.4. Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

- A new fold starts (`>1`) if the current line starts with one of the keywords *and* the previous line has no / a different keyword.
- Else, if the current line starts with one of the keywords, keep the fold level (`1`, or `=`), else no fold.

#### Implementation

```
set foldexpr=GetPamFold(v:lnum)
function! GetPamFold(lnum)
  let current  = matchstr(getline(a:lnum), '^\(NODE\|#\)')
  let previous = matchstr(getline(a:lnum - 1), '^\(NODE\|#\)')

  return ! empty(current) && current != previous ? '>1' : (empty(current) ? 0 : 1)
endfunction
```

Comment: That does work, thank you! I just can't figure out why... everything gets a fold level of 1 in my example, so there should just be one fold containing all the lines, right? Why does it do what I want?

Comment: The trick is the `>1`, which instructs Vim to start a _new_ fold (even if the level is the same as on the line before).

Comment: Oh ok, I did not see that this is possible in foldexpr. Thanks!